# Logstash : Filter column values in a log

Tags: logstash

I am using Logstash to parse and filter the data. The input data looks something like this:

```
Nov 28 23:00:31   Phase 0 ended (4 seconds)
                        X Time    X/S    X/SK S/C
                           0.140 [  : 1]   0% TEXT
                           0.270 [  : 1]   0% TEXT
                           0.080 [  : 1]   0% TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               B/W            R/W      S/R               SF            V    P/W

               0               0      [: : 0]          7535996       text   text                                       
               0               3      [: : 0]          7535996       text   text 
              1235             2      [: : 0]          7535996       text   text 
               out             0      [: : 0]          7535996       text   text
               0               0      [: : 0]          7535996       text   text             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to access R/W column values. Can anyone help me solving the problem ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: What quant meant is that you should also provide your logstash configuration (or at least the parts relevant to your current issue)

Comment: Iam using Logstash version 6.5.1

Comment: I have an unstructured log file which contains the above format. I want to filter the values of individual columns. The rows does not contain a specific pattern. The first column B/W can contain either a number or a string. I want the count of R/W column which is of type number. How can I filter them ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to build up your pattern.  Start at the left, so conquer the numeric value for "B/W" first.  If that works, then add in the numeric value for "R/W".  If you need to parse out other columns, keep adding them.

Comment: Thanks for the Response.

But grok debugger didn't work in my case. The first column can be of number or string and grok debugger could not find the pattern.

Comment: Then try %{WORD}.  There are a million patterns, and you can always build your own.

Comment: I tried with %{WORD}. For the input : 
           B/W                               
               c                                                
               0               
               3                 
               0
The output is something like this : 
{
  "WORD": [
    [
      "B"
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that WORD doesn't like punctuation.   Try DATA.  It'll be in your best interest to become familiar with the built-in patterns.  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#